Improving the Insert command with a Sequence in Oracle DB
I`m trying to insert multiple lines on a table. Some attributes are being provided in the INSERT, one of them is a client code, provided by a Sequence. How to execute this in one batch. I had to go line by line. BD Oracle 21-c. Thanks in advance!
INSERT ALL   
   INTO clinica_medica_t_convenios(id_cod_convenio, cnpj_convenio, nome_convenio,    nome_resp_conv, tel_resp_conv) 
   VALUES(s_cod_convenios.nextval,74566320001133,'Hapvida','Zeca Soares','312237702')
   SELECT * FROM dual;
    
INSERT ALL  
   INTO clinica_medica_t_convenios(id_cod_convenio, cnpj_convenio, nome_convenio, nome_resp_conv, tel_resp_conv) 
   VALUES(s_cod_convenios.nextval,10239980001754,'Bradesco Saude','Josenilton de Paula','217107844')
   SELECT * FROM dual;
   
-- Sequence created
 
CREATE SEQUENCE s_cod_convenios 
    MINVALUE 100
    MAXVALUE 999
    START WITH 100
    INCREMENT BY 1
    CACHE 10;

I would like to avoid include an insert for each line and also the select from dual, if its possible.

Does the id_cod_convenio column value always come from the sequence?  If so, then I think it would be better to define that column as an autoincrement primary key, instead of having to provide an actual value for each insert.

Anyway you must know that NEXTVAL will be evaluate only once per statement so you can't use it in INSERT ALL with multiple INSERT - that will generate dup PKs - unless wrapping it in a function.

I suggest you not try to achieve these goals. At low volume, you will want to insert one row at a time. It gives you the greatest control. Drop the dual use, it serves no purpose, and drop the ALL clause. Just do a normal INSERT INTO ... VALUES. If you do get to where you're loading hundreds of thousands of rows all at once, then you should learn how to do bulk binds from the client-side, the implementation of which depends on the client technology, but it will not involve an INSERT ALL.
